# Lines intersection using Boost Geometry

Tags: c++, boost, line, boost-geometry, line-intersection

How line can be represented using Boost Geometry?

I don't need finite segment, but I need infinite lines (maybe [Segment](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/libs/geometry/doc/html/geometry/reference/models/model_segment.html) or [Linestring](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/libs/geometry/doc/html/geometry/reference/concepts/concept_linestring.html) can be extended?)

As I understand I can use `boost::geometry::intersects`, but I don't know how to define infinite line.

Comment: Boost.Geometry doesn't have an intinite Line or Ray concept.

Comment: @Vertexwahn  there is no way to do line-line intersection in Boost?

Comment: Not for infinite lines so far...

Comment: Line intersection an be approximated by a segment with the endpoints very far from each other.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to test whether an infinite line `A` intersects a line segment `B`, this can be done using [`boost::geometry::strategy::side::side_by_triangle`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_65_1/libs/geometry/doc/html/geometry/reference/strategies/strategy_side_side_by_triangle.html):

```
template <typename Point>
struct line
{
    boost::geometry::model::segment<Point> segment;
};

template <typename Point>
bool intersects(line<Point> const& A, boost::geometry::model::segment<Point> const& B)
{
    using side = boost::geometry::strategy::side::side_by_triangle<>;
    auto const firstSide  = side::apply(A.segment.first, A.segment.second, B.first);
    auto const secondSide = side::apply(A.segment.first, A.segment.second, B.second);
    return firstSide == 0 || secondSide == 0 || (firstSide < 0) != (secondSide < 0);
}
```

The `line` type simply represents a line using a segment that is part of that line, but as a separate type so it can be distinguished from a segment by the type system, for the purposes of overloading.

It first queries on which side of `A` the two endpoints (`first` and `second`) of `B` lie. Then, if either of `firstSide` or `secondSide` are zero, this means the corresponding endpoint is touching `A`, so `intersects` is true. Otherwise, `intersects` is true iff the endpoints are on opposite sides of `A`.