# Most common way to compute line line intersection C++?

Tags: c++, boost, geometry, line, point

Seems [there is no way to compute line line intersection using `boost::geometry`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34133160/lines-intersection-using-boost-geometry), but I wonder what is the most common way to do it in C++?

I need intersection algorithms for two infinite lines in 2D, if it will be faster it can be two different functions like:

```
bool line_intersection(line,line);
point line_intersetion(line,line);
```

P.S. I really try to avoid a wheel invention, so incline to use some library.

Comment: If you're asking for links to, or recommendations for a library then your question is off-topic. If not then your question is to broad.

Comment: How do you represent a line.. two points? hough-space? m,p ?

Comment: Each line is represented as y = kx +b, and in intersection point x and y values for both lines are equal, so we can find it by equation {y = k1x + b1; y = k2x + b2}

Comment: @HumamHelfawi line represented as two template points.

Comment: @Jackson no, solution in your topic actually for segment intersection.

Comment: 2D? 3D? You need to specify more clearly what you mean.

Comment: @mrgloom, you could try searching for homogeneous coordinates and line intersection

Comment: If the lines are both defined by two points, you'd better specify a prototype like `line_intersection(P0, P1, Q0, Q1)`.

Answer (score 1):

Express one of the lines in parametric form and the other in implicit form:

```
X = X0 + t (X1 - X0), Y= Y0 + t (Y1 - Y0)

S(X, Y) = (X - X2) (Y3 - Y2) - (Y - Y2) (X3 - X2) = 0
```

By linearity of the relations, you have

```
S(X, Y) = S(X0, Y0) + t (S(X1, Y1) - S(X0, Y0)) = S0 + t (S1 - S0) = 0
```

From this you get `t`, and from `t` the coordinates of the intersection.

It takes a total of 15 adds, 6 multiplies and a single divide.

Degeneracy is indicated by `S1 == S0`, meaning that the lines are parallel. In practice, the coordinates may not be exact because of truncation errors or others, so that test for equality to 0 can fail. A workaround is to consider the test

```
|S0 - S1| <= µ |S0|
```

for small `µ`.

Answer (score 0):

This code should work for you. You may be able to optimize it a bit:

```
template <class Tpoint>
    Tpoint line<Tpoint>::intersect(const line& other) const{
        Tpoint x = other.first - first;
        Tpoint d1 = second - first;
        Tpoint d2 = other.second - other.first;

        auto cross = d1.x*d2.y - d1.y*d2.x;

        auto t1 = (x.x * d2.y - x.y * d2.x) / static_cast<float>(cross);
        return first + d1 * t1;

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The best algorithms that I've found for finding the intersection of lines are in: [Real Time Collision Detection by Christer Ericson](http://realtimecollisiondetection.net/), a copy of the book can be found [here](https://q3k.org/gentoomen/Game%20Development/Programming/Real-Time%20Collision%20Detection.pdf).

Chapter 5 from page 146 onwards describes how to find the closest point of 3D lines which is also the crossing point of 2D lines...  with example code in C.

Note: beware of parallel lines, they can cause divide by zero errors.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps a common way is to approximate the infinity? From my library using boost::geometry:

```
// prev and next are segments and RAY_LENGTH is a very large constant
// create 'lines'
auto prev_extended = extendSeg(prev, -RAY_LENGTH, RAY_LENGTH);
auto next_extended = extendSeg(next, -RAY_LENGTH, RAY_LENGTH);
// intersect!
Points_t isection_howmany;
bg::intersection(prev_extended, next_extended, isection_howmany);
```

then you could test whether the 'lines' intersect like this:

```
if (isection_howmany.empty())
    cout << "parallel";
else if (isection_howmany.size() == 2)
    cout << "collinear";
```

`extendSeg()` simply extends the segment in both directions by the given amounts.

---

Also bear in mind - to support an *infinite* line arithmetic the **point** type should also support an *infinite value*. However here the assumption is that you are looking for a numerical solution!

Comment: Also boost geometry has an intersects() function which returns bool I am yet to use it myself. :) http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/libs/geometry/doc/html/geometry/reference/algorithms/intersects/intersects_2_two_geometries.html

Answer (score 0):

You can try my code, I'm using `boost::geometry` and I put a small test case in the main function.

I define a class Line with two points as attributes.

Cross product is very a simple way to know if two lines intersect. In 2D, you can compute the perp dot product (see `perp` function) that is a projection of cross product on the normal vector of 2D plane. To compute it, you need to get a direction vector of each line (see `getVector` method).

In 2D, you can get the intersection point of two lines using perp dot product and parametric equation of line. I found an explanation [here](http://geomalgorithms.com/a05-_intersect-1.html).

The `intersect` function returns a boolean to check if two lines intersect. If they intersect, it computes the intersection point by reference.

```
#include <cmath>
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/geometry/geometry.hpp>
#include <boost/geometry/geometries/point_xy.hpp>

namespace bg = boost::geometry;

// Define two types Point and Vector for a better understanding
// (even if they derive from the same class)
typedef bg::model::d2::point_xy<double> Point;
typedef bg::model::d2::point_xy<double> Vector;

// Class to define a line with two points
class Line
{
  public:
    Line(const Point& point1,const Point& point2): p1(point1), p2(point2) {}
    ~Line() {}

    // Extract a direction vector
    Vector getVector() const 
    {
      Vector v(p2);
      bg::subtract_point(v,p1);
      return v;
    }

    Point p1;
    Point p2;
};

// Compute the perp dot product of vectors v1 and v2
double perp(const Vector& v1, const Vector& v2)
{
  return bg::get<0>(v1)*bg::get<1>(v2)-bg::get<1>(v1)*bg::get<0>(v2);
}

// Check if lines l1 and l2 intersect
// Provide intersection point by reference if true
bool intersect(const Line& l1, const Line& l2, Point& inter)
{
  Vector v1 = l1.getVector();
  Vector v2 = l2.getVector();

  if(std::abs(perp(v1,v2))>0.)
  {
    // Use parametric equation of lines to find intersection point
    Line l(l1.p1,l2.p1);
    Vector v = l.getVector();
    double t = perp(v,v2)/perp(v1,v2);
    inter = v1;
    bg::multiply_value(inter,t);
    bg::add_point(inter,l.p1);
    return true;
  }
  else return false;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  Point p1(0.,0.);
  Point p2(1.,0.);
  Point p3(0.,1.);
  Point p4(0.,2.);
  Line l1(p1,p2);
  Line l2(p3,p4);

  Point inter;
  if( intersect(l1,l2,inter) )
  {
    std::cout<<"Coordinates of intersection: "<<inter.x()<<" "<<inter.y()<<std::endl;
  }

  return 0;
}
```

**EDIT:** more detail on cross product and perp dot product + delete `tol` argument (off topic)

Comment: cross product is a vector by definition, but in your code it's scalar?

Comment: Yes I compute a scalar because only the component perpendicular to the 2D plane is non-zero. [Take a look to this explanation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/243945/calculating-a-2d-vectors-cross-product)

Comment: You can see it as the perp dot product. I'll edit my post :)

Comment: It does report lines with intersecting "angles," which if not limited by length of line span would eventually intersect, but also incorrectly reports line spans as having an intersection, that do not actually intersect. Try p1{300, 500}, p2{300, 300}, p3{200, 200}, p4{500, 200}  While their angles are intersecting, the actual line spans are not.

Comment: @NpC0mpl3t3 mrgloom wanted a function to calculate the intersection point between 2 infinite lines. I'm not computing the intersection point between two line segments. In your example, the both infinite lines (p1p2) and (p3p4) have an intersection point whereas the both segment lines [p1p2] and [p3p4] don't.

Comment: @cromod That's Exactly why it doesn't perform what it's advertised as doing. It will report an intersection for lines, in which the discrete points do not result in lines which intersect.

Answer (score 0):

To solve [this](https://leetcode-cn.com/problems/intersection-lcci) problem, I pieced together the following function, but unexpectedly found that it cannot calculate the intersection of line segments, but the intersection of lines.

```cpp
class Solution {
    typedef complex<double> point;
#define x real()
#define y imag()

    struct LinePara
    {
        double k;
        double b;
    };
    LinePara getLinePara(float x1, float y1, float x2, float y2)
    {
        LinePara ret;
        double m = x2 - x1;
        if (m == 0)
        {
            ret.k = 1000.0;
            ret.b = y1 - ret.k * x1;
        }
        else
        {
            ret.k = (y2 - y1) / (x2 - x1);
            ret.b = y1 - ret.k * x1;
        }
        return ret;
    }

    struct line {
        double a, b, c;
    };
    const double EPS = 1e-6;
    double det(double a, double b, double c, double d) {
        return a * d - b * c;
    }
    line convertLineParaToLine(LinePara s)
    {
        return line{ s.k,-1,s.b };
    }
    bool intersect(line m, line n, point& res) {
        double zn = det(m.a, m.b, n.a, n.b);
        if (abs(zn) < EPS)
            return false;
        res.real(-det(m.c, m.b, n.c, n.b) / zn);
        res.imag(-det(m.a, m.c, n.a, n.c) / zn);
        return true;
    }
    bool parallel(line m, line n) {
        return abs(det(m.a, m.b, n.a, n.b)) < EPS;
    }
    bool equivalent(line m, line n) {
        return abs(det(m.a, m.b, n.a, n.b)) < EPS
            && abs(det(m.a, m.c, n.a, n.c)) < EPS
            && abs(det(m.b, m.c, n.b, n.c)) < EPS;
    }
    vector<double> mian(vector<vector<double>> line1, vector<vector<double>> line2)
    {
        vector<point> points;
        points.push_back(point(line1[0][0], line1[0][1]));
        points.push_back(point(line1[1][0], line1[1][1]));
        points.push_back(point(line2[0][0], line2[0][1]));
        points.push_back(point(line2[1][0], line2[1][1]));

        line li1 = convertLineParaToLine(getLinePara(line1[0][0], line1[0][1], line1[1][0], line1[1][1]));
        line li2 = convertLineParaToLine(getLinePara(line2[0][0], line2[0][1], line2[1][0], line2[1][1]));
        point pos;
        if (intersect(li1, li2, pos))
        {
            return{ pos.x ,pos.y };
        }
        else
        {
            if (equivalent(li1, li2)) {
                if (points[1].x < points[2].x)
                {
                    return vector<double>{ points[1].x, points[1].y };
                }
                else if (points[1].x > points[2].x)
                {
                    return vector<double>{ points[2].x, points[2].y };
                }
                else if (points[1].x == points[2].x)
                {
                    if (points[1].y < points[2].y)
                    {
                        return vector<double>{ points[1].x, points[1].y };
                    }
                    else if (points[1].y > points[2].y)
                    {
                        return vector<double>{ points[2].x, points[2].y };
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    return vector<double>{ points[2].x, points[2].y };
                }
            }
            else
            {
                return {}/* << "平行！"*/;
            }
            return {};
        }
    }
public:
    vector<double> intersection(vector<int>& start1, vector<int>& end1, vector<int>& start2, vector<int>& end2) {
        vector<vector<double>> line1{ {(double)start1[0],(double)start1[1]},{(double)end1[0],(double)end1[1] } };
        vector<vector<double>> line2{ {(double)start2[0],(double)start2[1]},{(double)end2[0],(double)end2[1] } };
        return mian(line1, line2);
    }
};
```

From [there](https://cp-algorithms.com/geometry/lines-intersection.html)